# How can named local AMD modules be imported with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd

I'm trying to use named AMD modules with `exports` since this is the format that TypeScript 1.8 uses to write AMD modules to a single file when `--outFile` is specified. However, webpack doesn't seem to handle `exports` correctly if the modules are defined in the same file.

With this is in `content.js`:

```
define('messages', [
    'require',
    'exports'
], function(require, exports) {
    'use strict';
    exports.itWorks = "It works from a local module?";
});

define([
    'require',
    'exports',
    'messages'
], function(require, exports, messages) {
    'use strict';
    exports.message = messages.itWorks;
});
```

there is a runtime error:

```
bundle.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itWorks' of undefined
```

This breaks because in the bundled code `__WEBPACK_LOCAL_MODULE_0__` is undefined, since the `'messages'` function uses `exports` instead of a return value.

This all works fine if `'messages'` is in a separate file. How can I use `exports` with webpack in a single file?

Here is the relevant build output formatted slightly for readability. The same `exports` object is passed into both modules (merging their exports together??) and `__WEBPACK_LOCAL_MODULE_0__` gets set to `undefined` so the first module doesn't get passed into the second:

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_LOCAL_MODULE_0__;
    var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;

    !(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, exports],
     __WEBPACK_LOCAL_MODULE_0__ = (function(require, exports) {
        'use strict';
        exports.itWorks = "It works from a local module?";
    }.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__)));

    !(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, exports, __WEBPACK_LOCAL_MODULE_0__],
     __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function(require, exports, messages) {
        'use strict';
        exports.message = messages.itWorks;
    }.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__),

     __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
}
```